# Check All checkboxes not pushing names into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes. The javascript function allPosPlayersCheckboxes utilizes a "Check All" Checkbox that controls the others. The other functions (getPosAllFilterOptions & getPosPlayersFilterOptions) push the "name" properties into an array. This all is triggered when anything is changed on the form.

Suppose that all checkboxes are unchecked. If the user checks the "nonP_all" checkbox, it will automatically check the other checkboxes with class="nonP". Unfortunately, when the "name" properties are pushed into the array, it will not include any with class="nonP".

I"m unsure why they are not included in the array. Are the functions (getPosAllFilterOptions & getPosPlayersFilterOptions) not waiting for allPosPlayersCheckboxes to complete? Is there a way to have the secondary checkboxes included in the arrays? Thanks for any help!

```
<form id="formFilter">
  <h2>Filter options</h2>
 <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nonP_all" class="Pos_all" name="nonP" checked="checked">
    <label for="nonP">Position Players</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="C" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="C">
    <label for="C">C</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1B" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="1B">
    <label for="1B">1B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2B" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="2B">
    <label for="2B">2B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3B" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="3B">
    <label for="3B">3B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="SS" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="SS">
    <label for="SS">SS</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="LF" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="LF">
    <label for="LF">LF</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="CF" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="CF">
    <label for="CF">CF</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="RF" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="RF">
    <label for="RF">RF</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="DH" class="nonP" checked="checked" name="DH">
    <label for="DH">DH</label>
  </div>
```

```
function allPosPlayersCheckboxes(){
    $("#nonP_all").click(function(){ // When it is clicked....
        $('.nonP').prop('checked', this.checked); // Sets all to reflect "All"
    });
    $(".nonP").click(function(){ // When any are clicked....
        if($(".nonP").length == $(".nonP:checked").length){ // If all are checked...
            $("#nonP_all").prop("checked", true); // Sets "All" to "checked"
        }else{
            $("#nonP_all").prop("checked", false); // Sets "All" to "unchecked"
        }
    });
};

function getPosAllFilterOptions(){
    var pos_all_opts = new Array();
    $(".Pos_all:checked").each(function(){
        pos_all_opts.push($(this).attr('name')); // places names into array
    });
    return pos_all_opts;
}

function getPosPlayersFilterOptions(){
    var nonP_opts = new Array();
    $(".nonP:checked").each(function(){
        nonP_opts.push($(this).attr('name')); // places names into array
    });
    return nonP_opts;
}

var $formFilter = $("#formFilter");
$formFilter.change(function(){
    allPosPlayersCheckboxes();
    var pos_all_opts = getPosAllFilterOptions();
    var nonP_opts = getPosPlayersFilterOptions();
    console.log("pos_all_opts = " + pos_all_opts);
    console.log("nonP_opts = " + nonP_opts);
    updateQuery(pos_all_opts, nonP_opts);
});

updateQuery();
```

Comment: I copied the above code and it appears to work:
pos_all_opts = nonP; nonP_opts = ; pos_all_opts = ; nonP_opts = C,1B,2B,3B,SS,LF,CF,RF,DH;

The only comment is that the html is missing a closing </form> tag

Comment: Seems to work fine [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m75ejeaw/)

Comment: drneel, The "Check All" function works well, but the gathering of the names into an array isn't working. The console.log should show pos_all_opts = nonP; nonP_opts = C,1B,2B,3B,SS,LF,CF,RF,DH; But instead, the nonP_opts array is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are having an issue is because the checking of the boxes event is being caught at the form change event handler, and the code that checks and unchecks all of the other boxes hasn't executed yet.  As a result when you call your functions, the count for checked boxes is 0.  This also happens when you uncheck one of the position checkboxes, eventually the pos_all_opts variable gets out of sync and is incorrect as well.

These click handlers don't need to be in a function.  They are handlers that are hooked into the behavior of your checkboxes.

```
$("#nonP_all").click(function(){ // When it is clicked....
    $('.nonP').prop('checked', this.checked); // Sets all to reflect "All"
});

$(".nonP").click(function(){ // When any are clicked....
    if($(".nonP").length == $(".nonP:checked").length){ // If all are checked...
        $("#nonP_all").prop("checked", true); // Sets "All" to "checked"
    }else{
        $("#nonP_all").prop("checked", false); // Sets "All" to "unchecked"
    }
});
```

This is probably a little less than ideal, but it works.  The code that was in the functions to build the arrays has been moved into the change handler for the form.

```
$("#formFilter").change(function(event){
    var pos_all_opts = [];
    var nonP_opts = [];

    if(event.target === $("#nonP_all")[0] && event.target.checked) {
        pos_all_opts = 'nonP';
        $(".nonP").each(function(){
            nonP_opts.push($(this).attr('name')); // places names into array
        });
    } else if(event.target === $("#nonP_all")[0] && !event.target.checked) {
        pos_all_opts = [];
        nonP_opts = [];
    } else if(event.target !== $("#nonP_all")[0] && $(".nonP:checked").length  === 9) {
        pos_all_opts = 'nonP';
        $(".nonP").each(function(){
            nonP_opts.push($(this).attr('name')); // places names into array
        });
    } else {
        pos_all_opts = [];
        $(".nonP:checked").each(function(){
            nonP_opts.push($(this).attr('name')); // places names into array
        });
    }

    console.log("pos_all_opts = " + pos_all_opts);
    console.log("nonP_opts = " + nonP_opts);
    updateQuery(pos_all_opts, nonP_opts);
});

updateQuery();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx2xv86b/) for reference